# Comparing Infinity

Tags: python, c++, infinity

While looking for infinity value, I found out that:
In case of Python 3.7, `INFINITY > INFINITY - 1` returns `False` and returns same if we do `INFINITY < INFINITY - 1`.

In case of C++ also, I get the same result that is `False`.

Is this happening because we don't have a proper definition for `INFINITY`? Right now we just know that it's just a huge number and we can not say that `INFINITY` starts after some specific number `'X'`.

Coming back to the problem:
Now, some number `x` is obviously greater than `x-1`. Why this is not case with `INFINITY`?

Python Code:

```
A = float('inf')
B = float('inf')

print(A > B-1) # returns False
print(A < B-1) # returns False
```

C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double a = numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    double b = numeric_limits<double>::infinity();

    if (a>(b-1)){cout<<"TRUE";}
    else {cout<<"FALSE"<<endl;} //returns else part- FALSE

    if (a<(b-1)){cout<<"TRUE";}
    else {cout<<"FALSE";} //returns else part- FALSE

    return 0;
}
```

For any other `number = 10`, `number > number - 1` will return `True` and `number < number - 1` will return `False`.

Comment: Are you asking about the concept of infinity in math or are you asking how infinity is represented on a computer?

Comment: how the infinity is represented on a computer?

Comment: In mathematics, `infinity - 1` is still `infinity`. So what? So if `a = infinity`, `b = infinity - 1`, and `a == b` is true, obviously `a > b` is false.

Comment: @fferri: what mathematics is that? Over real numbers, `x - 1` never equals `x`. Find me a definition of a mathematical infinity *as a value* and you'll find it's not something you find in real/complex math. And python/c++ standard libraries don't really cater to hyperreal numbers where you might find such things defined...

Comment: @souser12345 infinity is not a real number... often `inf` is defined as `inf > x` for all `x` in `N` (natural numbers)...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist that's what I'm trying to say. It's not a real number or a particular value. As a result, if you suddenly find yourself assigning "infinities" in float/double variables in python or C++, that's not mathematics you're doing.

Comment: @souser12345 and yet you can make it consistent and useful...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist you engineer types man :)

Comment: @souser12345 (theoretical) physicist, actually. so i don't really know whether to be insulted or if you are correct... :)

Comment: You are correct that infinity is not a real number. Quoting from the IEEE 754 standard: “The mathematical structure underpinning the arithmetic in this standard is the extended reals, that is, the set of real numbers together with positive and negative infinity.” And: “The behavior of infinity in floating-point arithmetic is derived from the limiting cases of real arithmetic with operands of arbitrarily large magnitude, when such a limit exists. Infinities shall be interpreted in the affine sense, that is: −∞ < {every finite number} < +∞.”

Comment: On the other hand, your statement that “that's not mathematics you're doing” is false. It is mathematics. Mathematics is not limited to real numbers or to complex numbers. It works with systems of a great many kinds. Some of them are extensions of things you learned in school. Some of them are novel. But they can be grounded in axioms and manipulated formally, and they are mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking arithmetically the assertion is correct that `x < x - 1`. However, that is not how computers "think". Floating point numbers suffer from limited precision. Not even this holds:

```
print(1e90 < 1e90 - 1)  # False
print(1e90 == 1e90 - 1)  # True
```

That is because `1e90 - 1` is rounded to `1e90` when using double precision.

Something similar happens when working with *infinity* values. Before comparing, the expression `inf - 1` is evaluated.
What does - `inf - 1` evaluate to? There is only a single value to [represent positive infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Representation_of_non-numbers) so `inf - 1` evaluates to `inf`.

In consequence, when you compare `inf < inf - 1` you actually compare `inf < inf` and that's why you get `False`.

Comment: This is incorrect with respect to infinity. Any common definition of infinity has the property `x+a = x` and `a*x = x` for all real numbers `a`

Comment: @YngveMoe yep, but I thought a more informal explanation might be appropriate here. Besides, I'm not sure if infinity is always defined like that.

Comment: You might be able to find another way of defining infinity with that property, but it's not anything I've ever seen in my maths degree.

Comment: @YngveMoe Well actually, I removed the part with 1 less than infinity. That should make the answer mathematically correct (and also simpler!). Do you agree?

Comment: That's much better

Answer (score 0):

Infinity is not a number, not at least a real/complex one. It cannot be represented as a single value in mathematical domains. As such, it's not a meaningful operation to perform arithmetic on an "infinity" or compare it with anything.

But the brave engineers over at IEEE did standardize  one way of representing infinity in their floating point standards. Their vision of an "infinity" should be well specified in IEEE-754.